# python 3 , import error in dns.resolver library

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns, import, domínio

I am not able to resolve this error
my python version is 3.10
it is giving error in importing dns.resolver
could anyone out there help me?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/Dantas/tmp/myprojects/venv/dns4.py", line 1, in 
import dns.resolver
ImportError: No module named resolver'

```
import dns.resolver

domain = 'domain.com'
records = ['A', 'AAAA', 'MX', 'NS']

for record in records:
   answer = dns.resolver.query(domain, record, raise_on_no_ansewer=False)
   if answer.rrset is not None:
     print(response.rrset)


    ns1.domain.com: 65,254,244,180
    ns2.domain.com: 65,254,244,180
    www.domain.com: 65,254,244,176
    ftp.domain.com: 65,254,238,128
    infranet.domain.com: 65,254,244,180
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:/Users/Dantas/tmp/myprojects/venv/dns4.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dns.resolver
    ImportError: No module named resolver'
```

Comment: qual a versão do python esta utilizando ? ....Ha mais de uma versão instalada: python 2.7. 3,5 ....esta utilizando algum ambiente virtual?

Answer (score -2):

Paulo,

You have to install the dnspython module to have access to the Python resolver.
In windows CMD as administrator or in linux shell also as root:

```
pip install dnspython
```

or:

link: https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html